# Вывод данных из БД MYSQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

Есть вот такой код:

```
<?php
$sql_works = "SELECT * FROM works LEFT JOIN otdel ON works.id = otdel.id_type LEFT JOIN exam ON otdel.id_otdel = exam.id_otd ";
$result    = mysql_query($sql_works);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $data[$row['name_work']][$row['name_otdel']][] = $row['name_exam'];
}

echo "<ul class='clop'>";
foreach ($data as $name_work => $otdel_array) {
    echo "<li class='work_title'>" . $name_work . "</li>";
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach ($otdel_array as $otdel_name => $exam_names) {
        echo "<li class='otdel'>" . $otdel_name . "</li>";
        echo "<ul><li class='bg_li'>" . implode('</li><li class="bg_li">', $exam_names) . "</li></ul>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
echo "</ul>";
?>
```

Как можно вывести все остальные данные из таблицы `exam` а не только `exam_name`?

Привожу код:

```
<?php

$sql_works = "SELECT * FROM works LEFT JOIN otdel ON works.id = otdel.id_type LEFT JOIN exam ON otdel.id_otdel = exam.id_otd LEFT JOIN child_exam ON exam.id_exam = child_exam.id_exam";
$result = mysql_query($sql_works);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if(isset($data[$row['name_work']][$row['name_otdel']][$row['name_exam']])){ $data[$row['name_work']][$row['name_otdel']][$row['name_exam']]['fields'] = $row; } $data[$row['name_work']][$row['name_otdel']][$row['name_exam']]['child'][] = $row['name_ch_exam'];
}


echo "<ul class='clop'>";
foreach ($data as $name_work => $otdel_array) {
    echo "<li class='work_title'>" . $name_work . "</li>" ;
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach ($otdel_array as $otdel_name => $exam_names) {
        echo "<li class='otdel'>" . $otdel_name . "</li>";
        echo "<ul>";
        foreach ($exam_names as $exam_name){ echo "<li class='bg_li'>".$exam_name['fields']['name_exam'] ." " .$exam_name['fields']['performer'] ."</li>"; echo "<ul><li>" . implode('</li><li>', $exam_names['child']) . "</li></ul>"; }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
echo "</ul>";

?>
```

Не выводятся данные из `child_exam`. Выдает ошибку  `implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed`

Comment: Уточните вопрос, какие именно поля есть в таблице, какие нужны, и что с ними планируется делать?

Comment: @Aries Ну помимо exam_name есть поля "performer" - заявитель, "date_start" - дата начала, "date_end" - дата окончания и т.д. Их нужно вывести вот  сюда echo "<ul><li class='bg_li'>" . implode('</li><li class="bg_li">', $exam_names ) .  "</li></ul>";

Answer (score 2):

Тогда надо присваивать не конкретное значение из таблицы exams, а всю строку а далее выводить значения из этой строки

```
   <?php


$sql_works = "SELECT * FROM works LEFT JOIN otdel ON works.id = otdel.id_type LEFT JOIN exam ON otdel.id_otdel = exam.id_otd ";
$result = mysql_query($sql_works);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $data[$row['name_work']][$row['name_otdel']][] = $row;
}


echo "<ul class='clop'>";
foreach ($data as $name_work => $otdel_array) {
    echo "<li class='work_title'>" . $name_work . "</li>" ;
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach ($otdel_array as $otdel_name => $exam_names) {
        echo "<li class='otdel'>" . $otdel_name . "</li>";
        echo "<ul>";
        foreach ($exam_names as $exam_name){
            echo "<li class='bg_li'>".$exam_name['exam_name'] ." " .$exam_name['TO CHTO NADO'] ."</li>";
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
echo "</ul>";
?>
```

**UPD**

Ну можно и так попробовать вывести. Но хотелось бы сделать `print_r($data)` чтобы увидеть что же он там нагенерировал интересного

```
<?php

$sql_works = "SELECT * FROM works "
        . "LEFT JOIN otdel ON works.id = otdel.id_type "
        . "LEFT JOIN exam ON otdel.id_otdel = exam.id_otd "
        . "LEFT JOIN child_exam ON exam.id_exam = child_exam.id_exam";
$result = mysql_query($sql_works);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if (isset($data[$row['name_work']][$row['name_otdel']][$row['name_exam']])) {
        $data[$row['name_work']][$row['name_otdel']][$row['name_exam']]['fields'] = $row;
    }
    $data[$row['name_work']][$row['name_otdel']][$row['name_exam']]['childs'][] = $row['name_ch_exam'];
}


echo "<ul class='clop'>";
foreach ($data as $name_work => $otdel_array) {
    echo "<li class='work_title'>" . $name_work . "</li>";
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach ($otdel_array as $otdel_name => $exam_names) {
        echo "<li class='otdel'>" . $otdel_name . "</li>";
        echo "<ul>";
        foreach ($exam_names as $exam_name) {
            echo "<li class='bg_li'>" . $exam_name['fields']['name_exam'] . " " . $exam_name['fields']['performer'] . "</li>";
            echo "<ul>";
            foreach ($exam_name['childs'] as $child) {
                echo "<li>" . $child . "</li>";
            }
            echo "</ul>";
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
echo "</ul>";
?>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! я так понимаю следующий уровень уже сложнее будет сделать?

Comment: Про какой следующий уровень идёт речь?

Comment: `We need to go deeper`

Comment: @kirillStaruhin Ну в смысле уровень вложенности.

Comment: надо смотреть конкретный пример

Comment: @KirillStaruhin Ну сейчас вложенность реализована как Работы=>Отделы=>Задачи, а нужно Работы=>Отделы=>Задачи=>Подзадачи. Подзадачи тоже отдельная таблица

Comment: тебе надо будет с каждого уровня надо будет выводить только название или так же и другие данные?

просто тогда надо будет делать немного другие массивы. которые будут содержать не только детей но и поля

Comment: @KirillStaruhin Первые два уровня с названиями, потом уровень с полями, а за ним уровень с названием.

Comment: незная что там внутри, что надо подобное делать:
`if(isset($data[$row['name_work']][$row['name_otdel']][$row['exam_name']])){
  $data[$row['name_work']][$row['name_otdel']][$row['exam_name']]['fields'] = $row;
 }
 $data[$row['name_work']][$row['name_otdel']][$row['exam_name']]['child'][] = $row['sub_exam_name'];`

и соответветсвенно для вывода
`foreach ($exam_names as $exam_name){
            echo "<li class='bg_li'>".$exam_name['fields']['exam_name'] ." " .$exam_name['fields']['TO CHTO NADO'] ."</li>";
   echo "<ul><li>" . implode('</li><li>', $exam_names['childs']) . "</li></ul>";
        }`

Comment: @KirillStaruhin Попробовал, не получилось. Исправил вопрос, вставил код который имею сейчас, если не трудно посмотрите.

Comment: во-первых - Вы не предоставили какие значения ещё надо выводить из за этого я просто указал sub_exam_name, не зная данных
во-вторых - MySQL SELECT остался как и прежде, так что скорей всего там нету таблицы из которой нам надо брать четвёртый уровень

Comment: @KirillStaruhin `sub_exam_name` заменил на `name_ch_exam`. SQL был `SELECT * FROM works LEFT JOIN otdel ON works.id = otdel.id_type LEFT JOIN exam ON otdel.id_otdel = exam.id_otd ` стал `SELECT * FROM works LEFT JOIN otdel ON works.id = otdel.id_type LEFT JOIN exam ON otdel.id_otdel = exam.id_otd LEFT JOIN child_exam ON exam.id_exam = child_exam.id_exam` и выводит то что я описал выше.

Comment: @АртёмРумянцев, не надо в комментариях задавать новые вопросы! Если вам ответили на поставленный вопрос правильно, отметьте ответ как верный галкой возле ответа и оформите новый вопрос!